# How to transfer data using Indy TCP Server/Client?

Tags: delphi, indy, transfer

I want to transfer data from the TIdTCPServer to the TIdTCPClient.

On the server side I have:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var x:Integer;
    Received:String;
    SendBuff:TBytes;
    hFile:THandle;
    fSize:Int64;
begin
 fSize:=0;
 if MOpenFileForRead(hFile,MGetExePath+'\test.jpg') then begin
  fSize:=MFileSize(hFile);
  SetLength(SendBuff,fSize);
  MReadFile(hFile,SendBuff[0],fSize);
  MCloseFile(hFile);
 end;

 // ... here the SendBuff contains valid data, I checked. 

 repeat
  Received:=AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
  if not AContext.Connection.Connected then Exit;
  if Received=CMD_TEST_FILE then begin
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(fSize);
   AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteBufferOpen;
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Write(SendBuff);
   AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteBufferClose;
  end;
 until False;
end;
```

And the client side:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var fSize:Int64;
    RecvBuff:TBytes;
    hFile:THandle;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(CMD_TEST_FILE);
  fSize:=IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadInt64;
  SetLength(RecvBuff,fSize);
  IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadBytes(RecvBuff,fSize);
  if MCreateFile(hFile, MGetExePath+'\new.jpg') then begin
   MWriteFile(hFile,RecvBuff[0],fSize);
   MCloseFile(hFile);
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ok');
end;
```

... but it's not working. I checked the read and write data functions used and they are ok. At the server the buffer is set ok, the file size arrives at client ok, but the content of the buffer at client is only zeros.

P.S: I want to send the file in this way not with stream or anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `ReadBytes()`, it has an optional `AAppend` parameter that is True by default:

```
procedure ReadBytes(var VBuffer: TIdBytes; AByteCount: Integer; AAppend: Boolean = True); virtual;
```

When true, it reads bytes from the socket and appends them to the end of the existing byte array. Since you are pre-allocating the array, the initial bytes are undefined and the file bytes follow after the undefined bytes.

To fix this, you need to either:

1. Stop pre-allocating the byte array, let `ReadBytes()` allocate it for you.

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     fSize: Int64;
     RecvBuff: TBytes;
     hFile: THandle;
   begin
     IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(CMD_TEST_FILE);
     fSize := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadInt64;
     // SetLength(RecvBuff,fSize); // <-- remove this line
     IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadBytes(RecvBuffer, fSize);
     if MCreateFile(hFile, MGetExePath+'\new.jpg') then
     begin
       MWriteFile(haile, RecvBuff[0], fSize);
       MCloseFile(hFile);
     end;
     Memo1.Lines.Add('ok');
   end;
   ```
2. pre-allocate the array, but set `AAppend` to False so the bytes fill the existing array instead of append to it.

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     fSize: Int64;
     RecvBuff: TBytes;
     hFile: THandle;
   begin
     IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(CMD_TEST_FILE);
     fSize := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadInt64;
     SetLength(RecvBuff, fSize);
     IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadBytes(RecvBuff, fSize, False);
     if MCreateFile(hFile, MGetExePath+'\new.jpg') then
     begin
       MWriteFile(haile, RecvBuff[0], fSize);
       MCloseFile(hFile);
     end;
     Memo1.Lines.Add('ok');
   end;
   ```

---

**Update**: That being said, I strongly suggest you use a `TStream` instead, despite you saying you do not want to. It will greatly simplify the code and memory management, without breaking the communication protocol you have chosen to use:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Data := TFileStream.Create(MGetExePath+'\test.jpg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
end;

TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Received: String;
begin
  Received := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  if Received = CMD_TEST_FILE then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(TStream(AContext.Data), 0, True);
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: string;
  Strm: TStream;
begin
  FileName := MGetExePath+'\new.jpg';
  Strm := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  try
    try
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn
(CMD_TEST_FILE);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm, -1, False);
    finally
      Strm.Free;
    end;
  except
    DeleteFile(FileName);
    raise;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ok');
end;
```